# Sencha touch, adding images, button and list on a view

Tags: extjs, navigation, touch

I've integrated a slide navigation http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/ in my existing app but I want to add an image, few buttons and text below the list.

Here is a complete code of my navigation view.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Navigation', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    alias: 'widget.navigation',
    xtype: 'navigation',
    requires : ['Ext.data.Store'],

    config: {
        cls : 'nav-list',
        onItemDisclosure : true,
        items: [{               
            xtype: 'list',
            store: {
                fields: ['title', 'event'],
                data : []
            },
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate( '{title}' )
        }]
    },


    initialize: function() {

        userJson = localStorage.getItem('userJson');

        var user = Ext.JSON.decode(userJson);
        console.log(user);
        if(user.id != ''){
            var first = user.name.trim().split(" ")[0];
            console.log(first);
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.down('list').getStore().add([{title: 'Home', event: 'loadDashboard' } ]); 
            this.down('list').getStore().add([{title: first, event: 'loadProfile' } ]);


        }


    },
});
```

Is it possible to achieve that?

Application flow is:

After successful login, user is redirected to a dashboard, I've added a list icon button in left (at the toolbar), that slides and display the navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different component. It doesnt have to be an Ext.List, you can use an hbox panel with a list in one of items. For example, I'have forked it in git to have a nested list instead of a list: https://github.com/azche/slidenav.

Hope it helps-

Comment: I downloaded your forked version, setup but it has 7 erros, so it did not work.